# How do you create a vertical linear gradient in adobe flash professional cs5 or cs6

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, gradient, flash-cs6

If you go to the color picker and select a linear gradient you always get a horizontal linear gradient. How do you rotate the gradient 90 degrees to create a gradient moving from top to bottom in adobe flash professional cs5 or 6?

My problem stems from the inability to create vertical linear gradient on a rounded rectangle. 
I can transform and rotate the button to get the proper gradient but the button edges get distorted.

I start with:

[image]

I end with:

[image]

Here is the color picker i am using. I don't see a angle option for gradients.

[image: color picker]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the Gradient Transform Tool (F) which you've already found, you can hold and drag with the Paint Bucket (K) to set the direction of a gradient. If you then click on the new fill, it will automatically scale the gradient to fit the container exactly too.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Silly me there is a tool called the "Gradient Transform Tool". Hotkey "f". Blarg.

What i ended up doing was

1. Converting my rounded rectangle into a movie clip symbol
2. Adding a masking layer with the button form
3. Creating a second layer with the correctly rotated gradient underneath the mask.
4. Rendering a instance of my new symbol.

Kind of annoying but it works. Would still love to know if there is a easier way to do it.